# how to send two variables to the procedure called in application.ontime in VBA?

Tags: vba

to send one variable to the procedure MyMacro in application.ontime in VBA :

```
    strText = "Hello!" 
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "'MyMacro """ & strText & """'"
```

but how to send two variables?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean two string variables

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "'MyMacro """ & strText & _
                                             """, """ & StrText2 & """'"
```